# Assigning int* to an int[] does not work as expected in dev c++

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

The following **C** code assigns a pointer to an array:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// ders 5 : Diziler vs. Isaretciler 
int main(){
    int array[20];
    int i;
    int* pointer = (int* )array;
    // Fill the array with numbers from 0 to 20
    for (i=1; i<=20; i++){
        array[i] = i;
    }

    printf("5th element of the array: %d \n", array[4]);
    printf("array: %d pointer: %d \n",array,pointer);
    printf("The value pointed with (pointer+4) %d \n", *(pointer+4));       
}
```

That "pointer" must be equal to the "array" by value, but it is not. So it gives an error and collapses. I work with BloodShed Dev C++ IDE (but the program is in C).

[image: array and pointer values differ]

Comment: Decide on one languge C or C++ ?

Comment: This code is written completely in c, and the extension of the source file is also c. Isn't it possible to assign int[] to int* in C?

Comment: I have no idea what "dev-C++" is; is it a compiler that can handle C++ code, as well as C code? Do you have to tell the compiler it is C code, or will it recognise that automatically?

Comment: Dev C++ is the IDE I used. It uses mingw as compiler. You are right, I have to mention that dev C++ is the IDE (but I create c source code there)

Comment: @fercis there is nothing obvious about the code that says it is C code. The only indication about it being C here is your tag.

Comment: Works for me with gcc; but you may want to change %d to %p when you are printing a pointer. %d is for integers, not addresses.

Comment: So when I run your code, I get no error. It runs fine. Although there is a bug that you should use %p to print pointers and not %d. You can see here - https://ideone.com/zxs6iU

Comment: Don't use casts unless you **absolutely** have to **and** understand all implications! An array decays for most operators to a point to the first element. This includes assignment. And don't post images of text! Also passing a wrong type to `printf` invokes undefined behaviour. To print a `pointer use `%p` **and** pass the pointer as `void *` (this the only reason you should and have to cast to `void *`).

Comment: Your loop `for (i=1; i<=20; i++)` is stepping out of the `array` boundaries.  The loop should be `for (i=0; i<20; i++)` and the assignment should be `array[i] = i + 1;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don;t need to explicitly cast `int* pointer = (int* )array;` as `int* pointer = array;` itself returns the address of the first element which is same as the base address of the array.

Since you have declared the pointer to be `int` you can increment the pointer to access the next array value.

Also, in C the indexes start from zero so better having a loop starting from 
`for (i=0; i<20; i++){` which is the problem of your application crash. As C does not have boundary check and will call the value which is beyond the value allocated, it will throw a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 2):

```
    for (i=1; i<=20; i++){
```

C (and many other languages) starts index with zero. It shoule be the follows:

```
    for (i=0; i<20; i++){
```

*About the concept:*

Array is **not** pointer. It *decays* into pointer in particular context, and the decayed value is the address of the first element of the array.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(){
    int array[21];
    int i;
    int* pointer = array;
    // Fill the array with numbers from 0 to 20
    for (i=0; i<=20; i++){
        array[i] = i;
    }

    printf("5th element of the array: %d \n", array[4]);
    printf("array: %d pointer: %d \n",*array,*pointer);
    printf("The value pointed with (pointer+4) %d \n", *(pointer+4));       
}
```

Comment: Loop is Faulty.

Comment: It works good if the array size in 21 and not 20 which was in the edit.